# How to turn on GWT logging to see error stack trace?

Tags: java, exception, gwt, logging, signature

I'm pretty new to a project and when performing a certain action on the GUI a window pops up with the following error message

> could not get type signature for class Class$S7119

Now I want to see where this problem occurs and which class the culprit is. How can I turn on the GWT logging to see this information?

Comment: Do you see any errors when you compile the project? That's, typically, your first line of defense.

Answer (score 0):

This is how to turn GWT logging on. (in module file)

```
<inherits name="com.google.gwt.logging.Logging"/>
<set-property name="gwt.logging.logLevel" value="INFO"/>
<set-property name="gwt.logging.enabled" value="TRUE"/>
<!--<set-property name="gwt.logging.popupHandler" value="ENABLE" />-->
<set-property name="gwt.logging.consoleHandler" value="ENABLE"/>
```

EDIT: See [GWT project doc about logging](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideLogging.html).

Comment: I know see a logging window but unfortunately nothing is logged in it. Am I missing something?

Comment: How do you log in your app? ... I think you should just use java.util.Logger and log whatever you want and it should appeear in this window...

Comment: Note that the popup handler no longer exists in gwt 2.7+, check out the console handlers, etc.

Comment: Thanks I did not know about GWT 2.7